# ctx_ddl.sync_index running from java code

Tags: java, spring, database, oracle, spring-jdbc

I was asked to check if there is a way to execute the stored procedure ctx_ddl.sync_index  from the java code.

i have tried to execute it as a normal stored procedure  {ctx_ddl.sync_index{?,?}}  , i am using spring jdbc.

```
connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call ctx_ddl.sync_index(?,?)}");  
callableStatement.setString(1, "index");
callableStatement.setString(2, " 2M");
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

it is giving my an exception \n character found . i am not able copy the exception due to restriction on my pc (org pc), will try to add it.

how can we call this ctx_ddl.sync_index from java ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `call`:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call ctx_ddl.sync_index(?,?)}");
```

And fix a typo in your code: extra `}` after `?` in `.sync_index(?,?})}`

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call ctx_ddl.sync_index(?,?})}");
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo while coping i am using  the call , the syntax was correct for calling the procedure , even then i was getting the exception

Comment: @mktl which exception? Error code, error message?

Comment: Also please look at the updated answer: you have a typo - extra `}` in `.sync_index(?,?})}` after `?`